# Javascript: Why can't I get the value of this particular cell?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that looks at certain cell values in a table. However, when I try to specify the cell, I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined`

I'm using this Javascript notation. `maxRowCount` is the number of rows. `q` is shorthand for the table in question.

`var newOrder = q.rows[maxRowCount].cells[8].innerText;`

Is this notation correct? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Please post your markup. it looks like your problem might be in 'maxRowCount'

Comment: How are you getting your `q` value? That could be the issue. Also, your last row should be `maxRowCount-1` as arrays are 0 based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to get the last row, by using `rows[maxRowCount]`. The problem is that the arrays are zero-based, so if you have 10 rows, the first row will have index 0 and the last one index 9.

So in order to get the last row you should try this:

```
q.row[maxRowCount - 1]
```

Because according to the thrown error `rows[maxRowCount]` is undefined.

Comment: Yup, this was it! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Because rows are zero-indexed, a table with five rows will have its last row at row number 4.  So you have to do...

```
var newOrder = q.rows[maxRowCount - 1].cells[8].innerText;
```